# Stored procedure is returning a NULL output value when inserting a new row

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am inserting a row to a table using a stored procedure in SQL Server and asking it to return back the `scope_identity()` but its returning me the NULL value? So, how can I get the right value?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SALES.AddDiscount
    @Description NVARCHAR(255),
    @DiscountPct SMALLMONEY,
    @Type NVARCHAR(50),
    @Category NVARCHAR(50),
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME,
    @MinQty INT,
    @MaxQty INT,
    @NewProductID INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO SALES.SpecialOffer 
    VALUES (@Description, @DiscountPct, @Type, @Category, @StartDate, @EndDate,      @MinQty, @MaxQty);

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS scopeIdentity    
END

DECLARE @productnewid INT

EXECUTE SALES.AddDiscount 'THIS IS SQL SERVER',  1234,  'D',  'E',  '1989-01-01', '1989-12-29' , 5 , 10, @productnewid OUT
```

Comment: Please add your SALES.SpecialOffer table structure, create table script the better.

Answer (score 0):

First is to create an identity column on your table to get your scope_identity()

`[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,`

Assign your output variable in your `scope_identity()`

```
SELECT @NewProductID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 


BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO SALES.SpecialOffer VALUES( @Description, @DiscountPct,  @Type,      @Category,  @StartDate,  @EndDate,      @MinQty, @MaxQty);
    SELECT @NewProductID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
    RETURN
END
```

**Testing:**

```
DECLARE @productnewid INT
EXECUTE SALES.AddDiscount 'THIS IS SQL SERVER',  1234,  'D',  'E',  '1989-01-01', '1989-12-29' , 5 , 10, @productnewid OUT
SELECT @productnewid
```

Comment: Earlier its return me NULL, after assigning its return me nothing.

Comment: updated, add identity column `[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,`

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table? `scope_identity()` returns the last identity value assigned in the scope, which could be a trigger fired by the insert.

Comment: no, i don't have any trigger on the table. its just a simple table.

Comment: is it mandatory to have an identity column in the table where i am inserting the row ?

Comment: based on your stored procedure, its mandatory for  @NewProductID to have an integer value.

Comment: @KunalPatel its not mandatory to have an identity column, but `scope_identity()` has only one function, to return the last identity value in the current scope. So if you don't want an identity column you need to use the `output` clause, but to return what? You don't currently have an `id` in your table.

Comment: ok. So what should be the proper approach to resolve this question ?

Comment: The INSERT statement must be protected by appropriate error handling and any errors must be logged in the dbo.ErrorLog table. If the new insert succeeds, the @NewProductID parameter must be updated with the SCOPE_IDENTITY function value. A return value must also indicate success or failure for the insert.

Comment: @KunalPatel, your table requires auto increment column to get scope_identity()